# Converting js array into dictionary map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

I have this array:

```
["userconfig", "general", "name"]
```

and I would like it to look like this

```
data_structure["userconfig"]["general"]["name"]
```

I have tried this function:

```
inputID = "userconfig-general-name"

function GetDataByID(inputID){

    var position = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < inputID.length; i++) {
        var hirarchy = inputID[i].split('-');

        for (var index = 0; index < hirarchy.length; index++) {
            position += '["'+ hirarchy[index] +'"]';
        }
    }
    return data_structure[position];
}
```

while `hirarchy` is the array. I get the `[position]` as a string which is not working well.

how can I make a js function which builds the object path dynamically by an array?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what would be a value for such a structure?

Comment: I have edited my question, please review it again

Comment: Why you split `inputID[i]` by `'-'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below function will take an object to modify and an array filled with the properties needed:

```
function objPath(obj,path){
   path.forEach(function(item){
      obj[item] = {};
      obj = obj[item];
   });
}

var myobj = {};
objPath(myobj,["test","test2","test3"]);

console.log(myobj);
//outputs
Object {test: Object}
    test: Object
        test2: Object
            test3: Object
```

The function loops over the array creating the new object property as a new object. It then puts a reference to the new object into `obj` so that the next property on the new object can be made.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db4S8/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ["userconfig", "general", "name"];
var dataStructure = arr.reduceRight(function (value, key) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
}, 'myVal');
```

Ends up as:

```
{ userconfig : { general : { name : 'myVal' } } }
```

Note that you may need a polyfill for the `reduceRight` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight

Comment: Nice, +1. Note: `arr.reverse().reduce( /*same callback*/, 'myVal' )` is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function

```
var array = ["userconfig", "general", "name"];

function toAssociative(array) {
    var index = array.shift();
    var next = null;
    if (array.length > 0) {
        next = toAssociative(array);
    }

    var result = new Array();
    result[index] = next;

    return result;
}
```